# JQuery ValidateFlickering Email Message on Keyup

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the JQuery Validate plugin and am having issues with my email message "Please enter a valid email address." flickering constantly while I am typing.  This doesn't happen to any other field.  Everything else will just display the message until the rule is passed.  My validation code is below:

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("textonlyname", function( value, element ) {
        return /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/.test(value);
    }, "Please enter text and spaces only.");
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("complexpassword", function( value, element ) {
        return /\d/.test(value) && /[a-z]/.test(value) && /[A-Z]/.test(value);
    }, "Your password must contain at least one number, one upper-case character & one lower-case character.");

    $("#frmRegister").validate({
        rules: {
            txtRegisterName: {
                textonlyname: true
            },
            txtRegisterPassword: {
                complexpassword: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.next());
        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).next().show();
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).next().hide();
        },
        onkeyup: function( element, event ) {
            if ( event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "" ) {
                return;
            } else {
                this.element(element);
            }
        }
    });

    $("#frmLogin").validate();
```

The input element for the email using them HTML5 email type.

Any idea on how to stop it doing this?

Comment: You are overriding the default `onkeyup` function while complaining that it's broken.  Try removing your custom `onkeyup` function and just let the plugin's built-in function handle this.

Comment: You are also asking us about an email field where your code shows no such thing.  In other words, I created a demo based on the code you posted and it does not demonstrate any such flickering issues.  http://jsfiddle.net/eswwyzq8/

Comment: And finally, your OP is missing the relevant HTML required to make a proper demonstration.

Comment: Hello, comments were posted above along with an answer below, only in an effort to assist you.  Can you please provide some feedback to these things?  Thank-you.

Comment: My apologies, I have been unwell.  While this wasn't the solution it led me to the solution.  In the end I did a recode of it all as I clearly had misused some parts.  Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *I'm using the JQuery Validate plugin and am having issues with my email message "Please enter a valid email address." flickering constantly while I am typing.*

Your OP is missing all relevant HTML and there is no email validation code, so it's impossible for me to reproduce your flickering issue in a jsFiddle.

However, based on this code...

```
highlight: function (element) {
    $(element).next().show();
},
unhighlight: function (element) {
    $(element).next().hide();
}
```

You are not using the `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions as intended.  [These callbacks are meant for "highlighting" the field by adding/removing the relevant classes for valid/invalid](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight).

It appears as if you're instead trying to use these to toggle the error message element.  Since the plugin already handles toggling all messages automatically, you are probably causing a condition where highlight/unhighlight are fighting against this default behavior and that's manifested as flickering.

---

I also don't understand why you're using a custom `onkeyup` function when you're claiming to have issues during the keyup event.  Remove your custom `onkeyup` function to see if the default keyup behavior, built into the plugin, is adequate before making any modifications.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/81poLnLg/**

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The custom keyup was to try and get the errors displaying before the first blue which was happening for me.  I obviously had been doing this all wrong and misusing some sections and did a complete recode which seems to have resolved my problems.  Your feedback was very helpful though, thanks.